# Finding m-linearly independent columns of a matrix on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, polyhedra

Let us have a linear system Ax<= b. To find a vertex of this polyhedral set we need to choose m linearly independent columns of A and solve the system with the corresponding variables. How can I generate **all** the m-linearly-independent columns using MATLAB? I will then find all the vertices of the polyhedron I have.

What I can think about is: generate all the (n, m) combination of subsets. Check one by one ranks. Whenever the ranks are =m, take these solutions since they have full m-rank. Is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the linearly independent column you can use `eig` or `qr`.

for `eig` the eigenvalues equal to zero will indicate the non independent colums

for `qr` the zeros on the diagonal of R matrix will indicate the non independent colums

for example:

```
mat2 =
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 0     0     2
```

`qr` gives

```
R =
-1.414213562373095  -1.414213562373095  -1.414213562373095
               0                   0                   0
               0                   0   2.000000000000000
```

and `eig` gives

```
ans =
 2
 0
 2
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you :)